# Qué diferencias hay entre Netbeans y Eclipse, que producen incompatibilidad del código?

Tags: java, poo

Me esta sucediendo algo completamente raro con dos IDE...

este codigo funciona en Netbeans pero en eclipse no (Estoy usando Kubuntu).

Lo de abajo vendria a ser la calculadora donde ingresas 2 numeros con scanner.

```java
public class calculadora {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    suma suma = new suma();
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
    
    int a;
    int b;
    int opcion;
    public void varNumeros(){
       System.out.println("Ingrese un numero");
      a = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Ingrese otro numero");
      b = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Que formula necesita?");
      opcion = sc.nextInt();
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                suma.sumar();
                break;
            default:
        }
}
```

Y esto vendría a ser la suma.

```
public class suma{
    public void sumar() {
          calculadora cal = new calculadora();
        
        int num1 = cal.getA();
        System.out.println(num1);
        int num2 = cal.getB();
        int resultado = 0;
        
        resultado = num1 * num2;
        
        System.out.println("La multiplicacion es... " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Y esta la clase test.

```
public class calculadoratest {

public static void main(String args[]) {
   calculadora calcu = new calculadora();
   
   calcu.varNumeros();
}
```

}

Ahora... En netbeans funciona los `get` pero en eclipse no.
Netbeans agarra bien las variables generadas con Scanner y eclipse al ingresar las guarda pero cuando suma las pide resulta que da un valor de 0.

Desde ya muchas gracias (Soy nuevo en este mundito de la java)

Comment: Y como estas instanciado/usando las clases??

Comment: Buenas Christian, en una clase test la cual es la main.
cal.varNumeros()

Comment: podrías ponerla?

Comment: Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y por favor cambia el título para que sea una pregunta. "Pregunta básica de Java" no resume el problema. Algo como "¿Qué diferencias hay entre Netbeans y Eclipse, que producen incompatibilidad del código?" es una mejor idea. Además, sos el primer beneficiado al buscar una mejor pregunta. También revisá la redacción, así le simplificás las cosas a quien lee, y en lo posible provee un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable. ¡Todo esto ayuda a obtener más y mejores respuestas, y ayudar a otros!

Comment: Ahi la puse Christian.
Gracias por las correciones dario :)

Comment: El problema es que en la clase `suma` estas creando una nueva instancia de `calculadora` y al obtener las variables lo obtienes de la nueva instancia

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh claro es mejor decir que el metodo Suma tenga los argumentos a y b asi obtiene las variables en vez de con un getter.
Igual me sigue pareciendo raro que netbeans ignore ese error, gracias groso :D

Answer (score 4):

El problema no es que no se toma las variables, en realidad si se están tomando pero de diferentes instancias. Al momento de llamar al método `sumar()` de la clase `suma` estas creando una nueva instancia de la clase `calculadora` y estas obteniendo los valores de esa clase.

```java
public class suma{
    public void sumar() {
        calculadora cal = new calculadora(); //instancias nuevamente a la clase
        
        int num1 = cal.getA(); //obtienes los valores de la nueva instancia
        System.out.println(num1);
        int num2 = cal.getB();
        int resultado = 0;
        
    }
}
```

La solución es simple, hacer que el método `sumar` reciba parámetros con las variables a sumar y pasárselos en la clase `calculadora`

```java
public class suma{
    public void sumar(int num1, int num2) {
        
        int resultado = 0;
        
        resultado = num1 * num2;
        
        System.out.println("La multiplicacion es... " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Y en la clase `calculadora`:

```java
    // ...
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                int num1 = getA();
                int num2 = getB();
                suma.sumar(num1, num2);
                break;
            default:
              break;
        }
```

Como pequeño detalle debes de cambiar el nombre del método a `multiplicar` o cambiar el operador dentro del método, ya que no hay relación con el nombre y la operación que se realiza.

Como nota final todos los compiladores trabajan de forma diferente el código que compiles en netbeans no será igual al que compiles en eclipse o VScode.

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con que Eclipse, Netbeans y VScode compilen código de forma diferente, el compilador de java es un ejecutable javac que es parte de un jdk, ¿no será que el eclipse o el netbeans están usando un javac diferente?

Comment: @Tabitha en sí depende del compilador que se use. En el caso de Python, muchos piensan que su código es interpretado por python, pero el que lo interpreta es la implementación de CPython. Para el caso de Java un compilador genera el bytecode específico para una máquina y es la JVM quien interpreta ese bytecode, este puede ser diferente según el compilador que se haya usado. Por ejemplo el bytecode generado por GNU (para C) no será el mismo que el generado por Mingw